# Hacking python: postfix arguments

Tags: python, operators, overriding, postfix-operator

In Mathematica, I can do this

```
10+10 // Sqrt
```

that returns square root of 20. I'm trying to hack python to do the same. Like this:

```
10+10 // crazy.sqrt
```

How? Overriding operators in `crazy` class. But it's postfix. And according to this 
http://rgruet.free.fr/PQR26/PQR2.6.html#SpecialMethods

When I try to override any operator it's alwyas `self <operator> other` so in mentioned case I would have to do it for classes like int,string and ton of other - bad.

Is there a way around this? I would like to swap the order and redefine operator in `other`  class. (edit for clarification: `other`  is passed as argument to `self` class like this: self.__ operator __(...,other))

Comment: what ? I dont understand what you are trying to do `math.sqrt(20)` ...

Comment: I'm trying to add qick'n'dirty way to call functions like in mathematica that's just soo good.

I may have just found solution in  __coerce__() possibility. But I'm still interested in my question

Comment: why would you rather do `10 + 10 // sqrt` instead of `sqrt(10+10)`? I dont understand what is appealing about it ...

Comment: It sounds weird at first, but it's very useful in Mathematica when you experiment (similar to ipython). You can stack functions without needing to worry about brackets

Comment: The more I use Mathematica, the harder it is (especially in a REPL environment like ipython) to live without @, //, /@, @@, etc.

Answer (score 1):

maybe

```
class WeirdMath:
    def __init__(self,v):
        self.val = v
    def __floordiv__(self,other): #this tells us to apply whatever function to our value
        return other(self.val)

import math
print WeirdMath(10+10) // math.sqrt
print WeirdMath(["a","b","c"]) // " .. ".join
```

what might serve your needs is [forbiddenfruit](http://clarete.li/forbiddenfruit/)  (`$ easy_install forbiddenfruit`)

```
from forbiddenfruit import curse
def apply(self,method):
    return method(self)

curse(object,"apply",apply)
def cubed(n):
   return n**3
(10 + 10).apply(math.sqrt).apply(cubed)
"a big yellow house".apply(str.split).apply(" != ".join)
```

Comment: I don't want to add anything before `10+10` expression (that's the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You can hack this into Python (see ["Hacking Python without Hacking Python"](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/06/hacking-python-without-hacking-python.html)) or into IPython (see ["Custom Input Transformations"](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/config/inputtransforms.html#ast-transformations)).

To allow `10 + 10 ?? func`, you need `??` to be a low-precedence operator. But all of Python's low-precedence operators are either important (like `and`) or have meaning for ints (like `|`).
(See [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence))

Options:

1. Hack it in as `|`, which would look like a [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). This would be an Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) hack, and can possibly break an imported library that uses `|`.
2. Hack in a new operator (but don't use `//`, because that's important). You need to hack this in at the string level, before the AST.

---

For you, it might be enough to take advantage of Python's and IPython's various commands, and skip the bothersome hacking altogether.

First, instead of using `sqrt`, you can use Python's power operator.

```
(10+10) ** 0.5
```

Next, in Python/IPython, the underscore "`_`" represents "the last result". You can type this:

```
>>> 10 + 10
20
>>> sqrt(_)
4.47213595499958
```

(IPython also allows `_14` or `Out[14]` to mean "the result of the 14th input", and `__` and `___` to mean "second-to-last result" and "third-to-last result", respectively.)

Finally, with IPython, you can use functions without parentheses or commas if the line begins with a slash. (Enter `?` in IPython to see more information about this, or go [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#automatic-parentheses-and-quotes).)

```
In [6]: 10 + 10
Out[6]: 20

In [7]: /sqrt _
Out[7]: 4.47213595499958
```